# Unit test method that calls clearInterval with Jest and Enzyme on React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, testing, jestjs, enzyme

I have this React component and it have method that calls clearInterval to clear the interval set by other method

```js
class SomeComponent extends React.Component {
  setIntervalMethod = () => {
    this.interval = setInterval(this.method, 1000)
  }
  claerIntervalMethod = () => {
    clearInterval(this.interval)
  }
  
  render = () => null
}
```

How do i test those method?

edited: add test i did

```js
it('should call clearInterval()', () => {
  const mounted = shallow(<SomeComponent/>)
  const clearIntervalMethod = mounted.instance().clearIntervalMethod

  jest.useFakeTimers()
  clearIntervalMethod()
  expect(clearInterval).toHaveBeenCalledWith(expect.any(Function))
})
```

I've been googling for days, tried using `jest.useFakeTimers()` and call `expect(clearInterval).toHaveBeenCalledWith(expect.any(Function), 1000)` and a lot of other absurd way to test this method that i forgot, all to no avail.

So ... if anybody have a solution and kind enough to share here, i could pass this weekend with a happy smiling face and a heart full of joy.

Thanks in advance. Cheers!

Comment: `clearInterval` only takes the interval identifier as an argument. Try `expect(clearInterval).toHaveBeenCalledWith(expect.any(Function))`. Can you post your test file?

Comment: i added the test i did

Comment: Not sure if this is the actual code but `claerIntervalMethod` is misspelled in `SomeComponent`.

Answer (score 6):

`setInterval` [returns a number](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval), not a function. Try:

```
expect(clearInterval).toHaveBeenCalledWith(expect.any(Number))
```

Also, as mentioned in my comment, is misspelled in your example (not sure if actual code).

Comment: Folks using a newer version of Jest may need to set the fake timer mode:  `jest.useFakeTimers("legacy")`